# Inferring Nested Generic Parameter and Returning It from Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, interface, nested

I have an `IModelDefinition` like this:

```
export interface IModelDefinition<MT extends Typegoose, QT> {
  model: new () => MT;
}
```

QT isn't directly used in the interface itself, but it is passed as a helper to other functions, like this so Typescript can infer the QT automatically:

```
public async getSingleMatch<MT extends Typegoose, QT>(
    definition: ModelDefinition<MT, QT>,
    doc: QT
): Promise<MT> ...
```

And I call the function like this:

```
// Account is a ModelDefinition<AccountClass, {identifier: string} and
// if I remove the identifier string, it gives an error as I expect it to.
const account = await getSingleMatch(Account, {
      identifier: params.identifier,
});
```

Everything is right until getting the result. The result is type of `Typegoose`, but it should be of type `AccountClass` instead.
How can I solve this? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: To resolve misunderstanding; I can pass the types, but the whole reason I'm building this is to not to pass the types and make it infer automatically. Isn't there a way?

Comment: You are not passing the type in the generic function, you are only passing the parameters to the functions.

Comment: I can pass the types, but the whole reason I'm building this is to not to pass the types and make it infer automatically. Isn't there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also pass the type while calling the function.

```js
const account = await getSingleMatch<AccountClass, {identifier: string}>(Account, {identifier: params.identifier})
```

---

Now if you don't want the type to be passed every time you call the function and want it to infer the `AccountClass`, so just assign the default type `AccountClass` to the generic type.

```js
public async getSingleMatch<MT extends Typegoose = AccountClass, QT>(
    definition: ModelDefinition<MT, QT>,
    doc: QT
): Promise<MT> ...
```

Comment: I can pass the types, but the whole reason I'm building this is to not to pass the types and make it infer automatically. Isn't there a way?

Comment: When you make a function generic, it means it can be of any type which is supposed to be passed from the called of that function.

Comment: But if I removed the `<extends Typegoose>` clause, it would automatically infer right? Why is it not the case here?

Comment: It automatically infers Typegoose in my version, but I want it to infer `AccountClass` instead.

Comment: Whatever you want it to infer, just make it the default type, and ensure the default type should be compatible with the extended (Typegoose) type.

Comment: All classes passed there extend from Typegoose. If I pass `AccountClass` which extends from Typegoose, it infers TypeGoose but not `AccountClass`